# Right is Left on React Native

Tags: android, css, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

Trying to display a List item within renderRow.
I already implemented RTL in my project [as defined on react native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps.html), and I am getting a positive for `console.log(I18nManager.isRTL ? 'yes' : 'no')`.
I am trying to present a designed table cell, so it's an image, on top of which I am trying to layout my items. 
So the logo is defined in styles like this:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  logo:{
    position: 'absolute',
    top:11,
    right:11,
    width: 26,
    height: 26
  }
  frame: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:  'row',
    margin: 5,
  },


txtFirstName:{
    position:'absolute',
    top:7,
    right:40,
    marginRight:36,
    color:'white',
    fontSize:PixelRatio.get()*4/PixelRatio.getFontScale(),
    fontWeight:'bold',
    textAlign:'right',
    textShadowColor: 'black',
    textShadowOffset: {width:2,height:2},
    writingDirection : 'rtl'
  },

txtSecondName:{
    position:'absolute',
    top:17,
    right:40,
    marginRight:36,
    color:'white',
    fontSize:PixelRatio.get()*3/PixelRatio.getFontScale(),
    fontWeight:'bold',
    textAlign:'right',
    textShadowColor: 'black',
    textShadowOffset: {width:2,height:2},
    writingDirection : 'rtl'
  },

txtMainText:{
    position:'absolute',
    marginRight:36,
    color:'white',
    fontWeight:'bold',
    textAlign:'right',
    textShadowColor: 'black',
    textShadowOffset: {width:2,height:2},
    writingDirection : 'rtl',
    fontSize:PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(3),
  },

});

  renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
    return(
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.showBusiness(rowData)}>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Image style={styles.logo} resizeMode = 'cover' source=}require('../images/logo.png’){/>
        <Image source={require('../images/mainFrame.png’){ style={styles.frame}/>
    <Text style={[styles.txtMainText,styles.txtFirstName]}>
      טקסט
    </Text>
    <Text style={[styles.txtMainText,styles.txtSecondName]}>
      מיושר לימין
    </Text>

      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
  }
```

The result is disappointing.

Here's how it **should** look like:
[image]

and here's how it is right now:
[image]

What bothers me most is that it used to look okay, and I am not sure what blew it this way.

Also, the "Loading" text shows on the right of the window when the app starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As according to the documentation: "we map the left/right styles from the JS side to start/end, all left in code for RTL layout becomes "right" on screen, and right in code becomes "left" on screen."... Have you considered using left instead of right for your positioning? Alternatively, consider using flex-start or flex-end for the desired result.

Comment: And how you deal with a lot of text? they wrap to left, not to right.